# Cannot boot into ubuntu!

Tags: bootloader

I Successfully dual-booted win8 and ubuntu 13.04.
Now that i have changed my windows from win8 to win 7, i cant access my ubuntu bootloader, or option to boot into ubuntu. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

- Boot with the Ubuntu Live CD
- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair -y && sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`
- Reinstall grub

Comment: boot repair is great when it works - it never has for me

Comment: It's never *not* worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Installing windows 7 has installed the windows bootloader.

You need to reinstall grub - information for the various methods to do so can be found here.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2

Comment: Can i not use windows bootloader to boot into ubuntu rather that grub... i may prefer windows bootloader!

Comment: Use what you want - but that's going to be offtopic here - this isn't AskWindows ;)